# How to discard old entries in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to this one:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `record` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ref` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=245 ;
```

where `ref` is self-reference to the `record` table. `record` is filled with some `data` and sometimes, the `record` is updated with new data, BUT I keep a copy of the previous `record` without any modifications. So, when a `record` is updated, what really happens is that a new row is created with a `ref` to the previous `record`. It is, `record` is NULL unless it is replacing an old `record`.

So what I need is a mysql query that returns all new records. I have tried something like that, but it doesn't works:

```
SELECT * 
FROM record, record AS mref
WHERE record.id != mref.ref
```

Example:

```
id  |  data  |    date    | ref
--------------------------------
 1  |  32    | 2012-03-12 | NULL
 2  |  33    | 2012-03-12 | NULL
 3  |  34    | 2012-03-12 | NULL
 4  |  37    | 2012-03-12 | 1
 5  |  38    | 2012-03-12 | 2
```

The query should return:

```
id  |  data  |    date    | ref
--------------------------------
 3  |  34    | 2012-03-12 | NULL
 4  |  37    | 2012-03-12 | 1
 5  |  38    | 2012-03-12 | 2
```

due 1 and 2 have been overwritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all records which have no references to them from other records:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM record r
WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM record r2 where r2.ref = r.id)
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM record
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT ref FROM record)
```

Other approaches:

1. Recursive function which calculates whether the row with given ID is
   the most "fresh"
2. Create additional boolean field which would tell
   whether the row is actual. It can be set in the `ON UPDATE`
   triggers.

Comment: Added another query which can be faster than the first one.

Comment: First query **works**, second one is the first one I tried, but I don't know why it's not working.. (I discarded the IN query because normally it is very slow)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM record
WHERE record.id <> record.ref
```

Comment: That's exactly the same :) I've updated the question with an example

Answer (score 0):

if i undetstand this correctly, should you be able to use the IS NULL?

```
SELECT *
FROM record
WHERE ref IS NULL
```

Then you should get all records that has no reference, equals the newest

Comment: This will return the *first* record, not the last one. I've updated the question with an example